# Windows 11 Upgrade Installation Error 0xc1900101

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

During upgrading from Windows 10 to Windows 11, the installation fails with error `0xc1900101`.

The upgrade was launched using *Windows 11 Installation Assistant*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the upgrade to Windows 11 fails because I had **Google Drive for Desktop** installed and running.

The problem is that latest Google Drive for Desktop adds an actual **drive** (e.g. `G:`) and it causes problems with the upgrade.

*Solution*: Quit / Disable Google Drive for Desktop before upgrading.